# jQuery $.ajax function for $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax, .post

In the MvcMusicStore tutorial, it uses the $.post() to remove an item from the shoppingcart.  I want to practice my jQuery and want to convert it to $.ajax() call.  But it gave me a runtime error.  Can anyone tell me what went wrong in my codes.

this is $.post() call

```
    $.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart", { "id": recordToDelete },
        function (data) {
             Successful requests get here
             Update the page elements
            if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
            } else {
                $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
            }

            $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
            $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
            $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
        });
```

======================================================================================
this is my $.ajax() call.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            uri: "/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart",
            data: { "id": recordToDelete },
            success: function (d) {
                alert(d);
                if (d.ItemCount == 0) {
                    $('#row-' + d.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                } else {
                    $('#item-count-' + d.DeleteId).text(d.ItemCount);
                }

                $('#cart-total').text(d.CartTotal);
                $('#update-message').text(d.Message);
                $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + d.CartCount + ')');
            },
            dataType: "application/json"
        });
```

Comment: In you ajax you used uri instead of url

Answer (score 3):

use `url:` instead of `uri`

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart",
        data: { "id": recordToDelete },
        success: function (d) {
            alert(d);
            if (d.ItemCount == 0) {
                $('#row-' + d.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
            } else {
                $('#item-count-' + d.DeleteId).text(d.ItemCount);
            }

            $('#cart-total').text(d.CartTotal);
            $('#update-message').text(d.Message);
            $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + d.CartCount + ')');
        },
        dataType: "application/json"
    });
```

for more information visit on [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

the correct paramenter name is url not uri

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart",
        contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { id: recordToDelete },
        success: function (d) {
            alert(d);
            if (d.ItemCount == 0) {
                $('#row-' + d.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
            } else {
                $('#item-count-' + d.DeleteId).text(d.ItemCount);
            }

            $('#cart-total').text(d.CartTotal);
            $('#update-message').text(d.Message);
            $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + d.CartCount + ')');
        }

    });
```

try the above code once and let me know whether your problem still persists.....